# Altium Designer Black Screen in Gerber File

Tags: pcb-design, altium, gerber

I am currently working on a project. After everything done, I needed to make a Gerber File. I tried everything on the internet but I got nothing different than a black screen. I do not know which part I'm doing wrong.

[image: This is my project]

[image: Gerber File Step 1]

[image: Gerber File Step 2]

[image: Gerber File Step 3]

[image: Gerber File Step 4]

[image: Gerber File Final Step]

[image: Here is the result]

I only used Top Layer of PCB. I need your help. Thanks!

Comment: Let's start simple, the CAMTastic tool is really buggy, especially when it comes to display. Have you tried dragging the canvas (right-click and drag) to see if it shows up? Sometimes it takes a little bit of movement in order for the copper to show up.

Comment: Also, how are you entering the Gerber Setup? Are you doing File --> Fabrication Outputs --> Gerber Files?

Comment: @DerStrom8 I made Gerber file the same way you said. In .cam file, there is nothing to see or drag. Just black screen.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I created a random project that contains a LED and a resistor. Did same way to make a Gerber file and it happened. So maybe there is something wrong with my project?

Comment: I just tried it on my end with one of my existing boards and it worked no problem. Are you saying it worked when you created the LED & resistor project?

Comment: @DerStrom8 Yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77321/discussion-between-griffo-and-derstrom8).

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not available to chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find where the problem is but found the solution. A friend of mine told me that create a new project and move the schematic and PCB files to this folder. This was interestingly worked.

Comment: Interesting, must have been a bug in your old project file. Moving it to a new project worked around this. Very good, glad you got it sorted!